# Copy variable sized range VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet with data present in columns from column A to column V. I have a code which calculates the last row of the sheet. Now, I want to copy the last row i.e. for eg if the last row is 7 then I want to copy range A7 to V7 and paste it another worksheet.

```
'Here i is the LastRow
Workbooks("Co_insurer Sample File.xlsx").Worksheets("QUIDAM-INSURERS").Range("A:V" & i).Copy
Workbooks("Smart_Excel_BK.xlsm").Worksheets("Input").Range("I" & LastRowBK).Select
Workbooks("Smart_Excel_BK.xlsm").Worksheets("Input").Paste
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @AJD My code above is not working. It gives me application-defined or object-defined error. Can you correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Dim wsSource As worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet, rngCopy As Range

Set wsSource = Workbooks("Co_insurer Sample File.xlsx").Worksheets("QUIDAM-INSURERS")
Set wsDest = Workbooks("Smart_Excel_BK.xlsm").Worksheets("Input")

Set rngCopy = wsSource.Range("A" & i & ":V" & i)

rngCopy.Copy wsDest.Cells(LastRowKS + 1, "I")
```

To copy only values:

```
wsDest.Cells(LastRowKS + 1, "I").Resize( _
     rngCopy.Rows.Count, rngCopy.columns.Count).Value = rngCopy.Value
```

Comment: It gives me subscript out of range

Comment: Sounds like one or more of the workbook/worksheet names are incorrect

Comment: I'm sorry Tim. The code to copy is working fine. I am having a problem with pasting the copied content to another sheet. I want the copied content to be pasted at the "I" th column of another sheet. I am being given an error "Select method of range class failed"                                                               `Workbooks("Co_insurer Sample File.xlsx").Worksheets("QUIDAM-INSURERS").Range("A" & i & ":V" & i).Copy
            Workbooks("Smart_Excel_BK.xlsm").Worksheets("Input").Range("I" & LastRowKS).Select
            Workbooks("Smart_Excel_BK.xlsm").Worksheets("Input").Paste`

Comment: What's the value of `LastRowKS` (LastRowBK in your posted code) when it fails?  BTW you do not need to select a range to paste to it, and your code will function more reliably if you avoid select/activate.

Comment: I want the copied to content to be pasted at the LastRowKS+1th row from "I"th column to "AD" column. Can you help me with this code?

Comment: Thanks, man. Was stuck with this for an hour. Finally working

Comment: What do I need to change in the code if I need to paste without formatting i.e. only values?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Workbooks("Co_insurer Sample File.xlsx").Worksheets("QUIDAM-INSURERS").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Workbooks("Co_insurer Sample File.xlsx").Worksheets("QUIDAM-INSURERS").Range("A:V" & lastRow).Copy Workbooks("Smart_Excel_BK.xlsm").Worksheets("Input").Range("I" & lastRow)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did in the code I posted in my question. I used the variable i for LastRow instead